# Nurse/soldier romance in space

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I think this was a set of YA short stories focused on space. The one story I remember is about a nurse on a remote planet outpost who patches up a really injured soldier. He's completely out of it, but recognizes an "angel" took care of him. Later on, they're on the same space shuttle and meet with each other (totally breaking space protocol). I read this in the late 90's and it looked dated, but it was great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lovely people at Smart Bitches, Trashy Books solved this!
It was *A Sleeping Humpty Dumpty Beauty* by Anne McCaffrey, in the anthology *The Girl Who Heard Dragons*.

http://books.google.com.pk/books/about/The_Girl_Who_Heard_Dragons.html?id=Gz-YhN7GwrkC&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it makes me think of Joe Haldeman's Forever War

Comment: Not *The Forever War* which has a romance subplot but nothing like what the OP describes.

Comment: Hi- its not Joe Haldeman, but thank you!